# Have python 3 and pip 3 installed but pip -V shows 19.2.3

Tags: python, pip, macos-catalina

I have followed the instructions at https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac:
Now, `python -V` shows `3.8.1`, but `pip -V` still shows `19.2.3`.

I checked with `which pip3`, which shows 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3`, but using

`echo "alias pip=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3>> ~/.zshrc` does not seem to work.

`pip -V` gives: `pip 19.2.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`.

I have MacOS Cataline 10.15.3. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

There seems nothing wrong with your setup. `pip` has a version number that is independent of that of python. Your python version is `3.8` and the corresponding pip (which resides in `python3.8/site-packages/pip`) has version `19.2.3`. You have set up everything just fine

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In fact I was trying to install python in pyenv and get my IDLE to work. The following worked for me (mostly from https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1375; [Installed Python 3 on Mac OS X but its still Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921333/installed-python-3-on-mac-os-x-but-its-still-python-2-7); https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac,  with a few additional steps). Thanks for your help. I posted my solution at https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1375, too, for reference)

1. ran $`brew install pyenv`
2. ran $`brew install tcl-tk`

Output after "brew reinstall tcl-tk':

tcl-tk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because tk installs some X11 headers and macOS provides an (older) Tcl/Tk.

If you need to have tcl-tk first in your PATH run:

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

(I added it to ~/.zshrc as the first line)

For compilers to find tcl-tk you may need to set:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"

export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"
```

(I added these two to ~/.zshrc, too, after adding the above)

For pkg-config to find tcl-tk you may need to set:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig"
```

(I added this two to ~/.zshrc, too, after adding the above)

3. To get tcl-tk 8.6 to work with the pyenv install of python, I found:

/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build

and replaced the following:
$CONFIGURE_OPTS ${!PACKAGE_CONFIGURE_OPTS} "${!PACKAGE_CONFIGURE_OPTS_ARRAY}" || return 1
with:
$CONFIGURE_OPTS --with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6' ${!PACKAGE_CONFIGURE_OPTS} "${!PACKAGE_CONFIGURE_OPTS_ARRAY}" || return 1

4. ran $`pyenv install 3.8.1`
   Installed Python-3.8.1 to /Users/ryan/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1
5. ran $`pyenv global 3.8.1`

Refreshed the current terminal and checked

6. $pyenv version
   output: 3.8.1 (set by /Users/ryan/.pyenv/version)

Ran $`python -V`
output: Python 3.8.1

7. ran $`pip install --upgrade pip` (since I had previously already installed pip using $pip install)

output: Successfully installed pip-20.0.2

8. Tested my tcl-tk installation with $`python -m tkinter -c 'tkinter._test()'`
   Output: Tk window popped up. Hit ‘Quit’ to back to Terminal.
9. Ran $ `idle` 
   Output: Python 3.8.1 Shell window popped up.

The installation was done on a MacBook Pro with macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question, is it?